# How to replace ’ with ' in MySQL DB?

Tags: mysql

I've around 10000 records stored in MYSQL Database. 
I want to replace ’ with ' in a given table of MySQL DB (for all columns) 
Can you please suggest how it can be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try like this:

```
UPDATE table1 SET columnname = REPLACE(columnname, '\’', ''');
```

Also check the [Special Character Escape Sequences](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-literals.html#character-escape-sequences)

Answer (score -1):

First of all export your database then open it in text editor then find the string and then replace it with your new string and import db